# How to see JS prototype in VS Code using Code Runner extension?

Tags: javascript, prototype, vscode-code-runner

I am a beginner currently going through a JS tutorial on prototypes but I am unable to see the prototype property after running the code in VS with Code Runner. Is it not possible to see prototypes in VS code with Code Runner? Are there any other ways to access property?

[image: Code Runner in VS Code]
[image: Tutorial on JS Prototypes]

Comment: The view from your second screenshot comes from a debugger, which allows live inspection of the logged objects.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I didn't notice that it was different lol.